# When I deploy my next js app on cPanel, style is not working, style was written in sass

Tags: sass, next.js, deployment, less, cpanel

I have deployed my next js app on to cPanel, everything is ok, but it shows just html, scss files are not working. How can I fix it?

I have searched on google but could not find proper answer. I have no idea what to do. Has anyone encountered this problem?